# Where do my ex-wives go after we divorce?

Tags: fable-3

I think my wives divorced me because I had them both living in the same area. I want to get one of them back, but I have no idea where they have gone. After the second one divorced me it says she had left the region. Are they both taken out of the game when you divorce them, or are they still around?

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have been divorced there is no way to get them back as they leave and someone else replaces them.

Comment: They've despawned from the game entirely.